# Which $n$-gons of diameter 1 maximize the moment of inertia?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry

**Background:** Among convex plane $n$-gons of unit diameter, we can try to achieve:

- the largest area. (This is called the *biggest little polygon with $n$ sides*; for $n$ odd, the regular polygon on $n$ sides is known to be the biggest little $n$-gon; for $n=6$ the regular polygon is suboptimal and Ron Graham found an optimal polygon; for $n=8$ the regular polygon is again suboptimal; for higher even $n$ I am not sure).
- the largest width or the largest perimeter.  (The *Reinhardt polygons* maximize both of these.)
- the largest moment of inertia about an axis through the center of mass and normal to the plane (our present question).

**Question:** Among convex $n$-gons of diameter 1, which maximize this moment of inertia?

Comment: Perhaps someone can provide formulas for the moments of some regular polygons, Reinhardt polygons, and biggest little polygons? That would be a good place to start.

Comment: The recent article of http://www.math.toronto.edu/mccann/papers/LimMcCann20.pdf contains results on such variational questions.