# Which planar convex region with specified area and perimeter maximizes/minimizes Moment of Inertia?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, convex-geometry

By moment of inertia of a planar convex region C, here we mean its moment of inertia about an axis passing through the center of mass of C and perpendicular to the plane of C.

**Question:** For specified area and perimeter which C maximizes moment of inertia? Which shape of C minimizes it?

**Note 1:** One could ask variants with say, "specified area, perimeter and diameter" and so on.

**Note 2:** The same questions can be asked for other moments (moment of inertia is defined for square of distance from axis; other moments for other powers).

**Note 3:** Relaxing the requirement of convexity of C but with all other conditions fixed could have interesting implications for moments defined with respect to higher powers of the distance to axis.

Earlier questions: [To find the convex planar region minimizing diameter when area and perimeter are given](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/458813/to-find-the-convex-planar-region-minimizing-diameter-when-area-and-perimeter-are), [Which $n$-gons of diameter 1 maximize the moment of inertia?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/383032/which-n-gons-of-diameter-1-maximize-the-moment-of-inertia)